# Phoenix create index meet exception

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

When I want to **create index** on **a big hbase table** with more than **one hundred million rows** in the sqlline cmd, I got an exception after a few minutes. I don't known how to resovle this problem. My env is:

- hbase(main):001:0> version
  1.0.0-cdh5.4.2, rUnknown, Tue May 19 17:07:29 PDT 2015
- Phoenix
  Connected to: Phoenix (version 4.6)
  Driver: PhoenixEmbeddedDriver (version 4.6)
  Autocommit status: true

And the exception info look like:

```
15/12/11 14:20:08 WARN client.ScannerCallable: Ignore, probably already closed
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 37, already closed?
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2092)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31443)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2035)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:313)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.close(ScannerCallable.java:329)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:56)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.close(ClientScanner.java:507)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ScanningResultIterator.close(ScanningResultIterator.java:49)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.TableResultIterator.close(TableResultIterator.java:95)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixResultSet.close(PhoenixResultSet.java:162)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.UpsertCompiler.upsertSelect(UpsertCompiler.java:199)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.UpsertCompiler.access$000(UpsertCompiler.java:114)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.UpsertCompiler$UpsertingParallelIteratorFactory.mutate(UpsertCompiler.java:229)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.MutatingParallelIteratorFactory.newIterator(MutatingParallelIteratorFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ParallelIterators$1.call(ParallelIterators.java:109)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ParallelIterators$1.call(ParallelIterators.java:100)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.apache.phoenix.job.JobManager$InstrumentedJobFutureTask.run(JobManager.java:183)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 37, already closed?
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2092)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:31443)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2035)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:300)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:31889)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.close(ScannerCallable.java:327)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Do you create the index remotely or on the cluster. To my experience, when you create indexes remotely (or behind a vpn), it takes much more time than when you run the command on the cluster

Comment: I do create the index on the cluster. When I do create the index on a table with just about 1000w rows it work well . But I meet the exception above when the table is bigger. Do you meet this problem before?

Comment: Not really, I suggest to post your question in the phoenix email list as well. You may get some answers.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to HBase Scanner time out, Set the parameter `hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period` in `hbase-site.xml` to a sufficiently large value and restart the cluster.

However, its better to use Asynchronous Indexes when dealing with big tables containing millions of rows

Answer (score 0):

alright, I got some help from the phoenix official website:

https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html

for the introduction of 'Index Population' section, we can use create index asynchronously by including the ASYNC keyword in the index creation DDL statement when the source table is big.

example :

```
CREATE INDEX async_index ON my_schema.my_table (v) ASYNC
```

Then we can use the mapreduce tool 'IndexTool' to update our index table to be synchronized with the source table and then auto to set the index table to be active when the mapreduce job finished successfully.

example :

```
${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.index.IndexTool
  --schema MY_SCHEMA --data-table MY_TABLE --index-table ASYNC_IDX
  --output-path ASYNC_IDX_HFILES
```

This way can avoid casuing the exception above.